# AVCaptureSession can't startRunning between calls to beginConfiguration / commitConfiguration

Tags: ios, avfoundation, zxing

I'm trying to read **QR code** with **Zxing** :

```
self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

// Use the back camera
self.capture.delegate = self;
self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;

self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];
```

I'm getting this error :

***  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** AVCaptureSession can't startRunning between calls to beginConfiguration / commitConfiguration'

Answer (score 2):

It can work, if so

```
self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

// Use the back camera

self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;

self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];

self.capture.delegate = self; // this must be last.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hotfix Suggestion:

Go into  [ZXCapture start] and look comment the dispathc_asyn part:

```
// NSLog(@"start running");
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      [self.session startRunning];
//    });
```

I won't crash anymore but you will then block your main thread for the time the session needs to start -> Hotfix till the guys from zxing come up with a solution.